# Replace the missing values with other column from same data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Sector      Sect
SE1         SE1
SE2         SE2
SE1         NaN
SE1         SE1
SE2         SE2
NaN         SE3
SE4         SE4
NaN         SE4
SE1         NaN
SE2         NaN
```

I would like to replace the missing values in column Sector with the value in column Sect in pandas.

Expected Output

```
Sector      Sect
SE1         SE1
SE2         SE2
SE1         NaN
SE1         SE1
SE2         SE2
SE3         SE3
SE4         SE4
SE4         SE4
SE1         NaN
SE2         NaN
```

Comment: `df['Sector'] = df['Sector'].fillna('df['Sect'])`

Comment: if only there are two columns: `df = df.bfill(axis = 1)` also works

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, Kindly add your answer, I can accept your answer